# SupportMapFragment in TabHostFragment have ugly black background

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, maps

I have problem with Ice Cream Sandwich device. I use Tab Host Fragment with Support Map Fragment  and when I switching between Tabs I have black background under Support Map Fragment. How can I fix it??

```
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>




<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.example.user.tabhost_blackbackground.NiceFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I try to make transparent FrameLayout, but with no result

Comment: And i have tried to use NiceSupportMapFragment and it was no result too